# How to intercept every AJAX request from a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, wrapper, intercept

I need the way to intercept all ajax requests maded from page. So i need some wrapper to add my data to all users requests.

Comment: How are you making these requests?

Comment: How about using this library? https://github.com/slorber/ajax-interceptor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Huh... i made this work)))
with help of this topic [Extending an ActiveXObject in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797960/extending-an-activexobject-in-javascript/3202098#3202098)
i made script that intercept all ajax requests no matter what framework or browser do user use.

You can look at it here: [Script](http://gist.github.com/469941)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can get this out of the box . 
What you need here is a little restructuring of your client side code [ You should have already done that , but it is never too late :) ] .

Make a function that has the responsibility of interacting with server . Use this to make ALL your server requests and get data . After that whenever you need to do something at a application level ( like maybe caching data to avoid server side trip ) you can do in this function . 

So something like

```
xhr_request( url , callback_function, params ) ;
// where xhr_request is your custom function that takes care of server interaction .
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm  looking for the same thing i think i want to modify ajax reponse on the fly i find this i'll tell you but it's hard for a script kiddies like me

See the Enterprise JQuery article [Mock Your Ajax Requests with Mockjax for Rapid Development](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/).

Comment: This is not for mocking but for intercepting requests from any script on the page. For example you need to add debug for each request in console. As for me, i was using to make online proxy, so i was need possibility to change all request to my proxy server)
As for mocking you should use something more simpler)