# How can I intercept ajax responses in jQuery before the event handler?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'd like to register a global event handler for all AJAX requests, so that I can intercept and handle responses from the server *before* the specific event handler gets them.

For example, my code might have something like:

```
$("#placeholder").load("/fragments/userpics");
```

And I'd like to register a "before" event handler so that I could, for example, display a login box if a 401 response is returned, or maybe retry if there's a 503 response.

I thought that [`$.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) is where I would do something like this, but apparently it is only triggered **after** the event handler.

**UPDATE**: OK, here's what I got so far, with the help of @genesis:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // override success handling
        if(typeof(success) === "function") return success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    };
    var error = options.error;
    options.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // override error handling
        if(typeof(error) === "function") return error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    };
});
```

After doing some testing, it looks like I would also need to override `options.complete`.

However, this still doesn't cover all the bases, since you can also attach events directly to the jqXHR object, and changing `options` won't help in this case.

Any tips?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796951/1509853 ?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to handle the data coming back from the server before the event handler, use datafilter:

```
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
            //modify the data

            return data;
        }
    });
```

Comment: jQuery, not jquery

Comment: `dataFilter` doesn't called for erroneous response, only for success.

Answer (score 8):

> Handle custom Ajax options or modify existing options before each request is sent and before they are processed by $.ajax().

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

I bet it works for .load(), too

Comment: I might be misreading the original question or the jQuery docs, but it looks to me like `ajaxPrefilter` is going to intervene **before** the request is sent and @itsadok wants something to intervene **after** the request is sent and the response is received but before it gets processed.

Comment: @Rick, the trick is to override options.success and options.error. I'm still working it out, though.

Comment: @itsadok, wouldn't `ajaxComplete()` be the better place to catch it? Or is that too late in the cycle? I'll admit that jQuery is not my strong suit...

Comment: `ajaxPrefilter` appears to work for my use case, where I want to suppress the local error handler for http status code 401 (unathenticated) responses in favor of a global one.  `    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        var error = options.error;
        options.error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof (error) === "function" && jqXHR.status != 401) return error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        };
    });`

Comment: @itsadok - How did you get on with overriding the specific instance handlers without creating others?

Answer (score 1):

Hugo Forte has the correct answer, the only way to intercept an Ajax response before any event handlers are called is to use dataFilter.

I had to use this today to handle redirecting ajax responses on the client side without refactoring the code too much.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function (data, type) {
        if (data !== "" && data === "NOAUTH") {
            window.location = '/';
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```