# Is it possible to use Javascript to search Javascript code for all URLs the code would attempt to access?

Tags: javascript, ajax, search

Let's say I have an entire JS script in a string variable. Rather than executing the entire script, I merely want to evaluate its code enough to find out which URLs it would attempt to retrieve (via Ajax) if it were run.

I could just do a regex search on the code as text, but that wouldn't find URLs that were deliberately obfuscated using things like `replace()`.

This would need to be done using Javascript.

Could anyone provide at least a hint on how this might be possible, if it is at all possible?

Edit: For context, my project is to build a greasemonkey script that filters out facebook spamming scams from userscripts.org's script listing. I have something up already that does a simple text search for common facebook ajax URLs used for scamming, but scam authors are already trying to find ways around it. I need to somewhat reliably catch all Ajax URLs for checking, regardless of how they've been strung together and changed with string functions. See http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/163038 if interested.

Comment: you mentioned deliberate obfuscation of said URLs...is the "variable" a long string you are defining in a javascript enclosure?  If so obfuscation wouldn't matter at the javascript level and regex would indeed work

Comment: Let's say an "ajax" call means to you the use of an `ajax(url)` function. You could override `ajax(url)` to store your URLs instead of making ajax calls. What do you think about it?

Comment: @blint: That's an interesting idea, but I would have to redefine something lower-level to catch all the various Ajax functions/methods, like jQuery's $.ajax, $.get, etc, and whatever else exists. Is there one particular function or method they all use?

Comment: @Mike: The variable would be the result of an Ajax retrieval of a .js page. If Ajax calls in that page contain URLs built using functions or multiple concatenated strings, I think that would be a problem for regex. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic might help you: [intercept all ajax calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884616/intercept-all-ajax-calls)

Indeed, you could redefine XHR to make ajax calls behave how you intent to, not depending on Javascript frameworks:

```
var ajax_urls = new Array();
var XHR_backup = new Array();
XHR_backup.open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XHR_backup.send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

// Customize XHR behaviour
(function(XHR, ajax_urls) {
    "use strict";

    var open = XHR.prototype.open;
    var send = XHR.prototype.send;

    XHR.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        ajax_urls.push(url);
    };

    XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest, ajax_urls);

// Evaluate your script
eval(resultScript);

for (var i = 0; i < ajax_urls.length; i++) {
    alert('Hey, my super XHR fetched ' + ajax_urls[i] + ' !!');
}

// Restore initial XHR behaviour
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = XHR_backup.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = XHR_backup.send;
```

**Edit:** I haven't tested this snippet so I'm waiting for your feedback.

**Edit2:** Tested and working! http://jsfiddle.net/3qVUP/1/

Comment: If I'm understanding this, I should put this snippet above `eval(retrievedScript)`, only with the suggested lines commented out, and the URLs should be pushed into the ajax_urls array? How would I prevent this from interfering with my initial retrieval of the JS page using jQuery's $.ajax?

Comment: If the source I mentioned says right, you could paste this snippet before your `eval()` without commenting anything and you would save your URLs while calling them. If you want to restore "default" XHR behaviour, I'm making some edit for this.

Comment: I'm finding this does work but only for some scripts. Using `alert()` I determined that everything tends to work up until the `eval()` statement, at which point execution stops, for most of the scripts I've tried evaluating with it. Ironically, it seems to break when the evaluated script uses `xmlhttp` for Ajax, but it works when the evaluated script uses `$.ajax` instead (this is just based on my very limited testing though, so this actually might have nothing to do with which ones work).

Comment: I think I've hit a wall... I guess lots of things in the retrieved script could potentially break `eval()`, so it's not a great way to test unknown scripts. Thanks so much for this suggestion, it was a great idea! But I have a feeling I've been barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I've added details to my question explaining what this will be for, in case it helps.

Comment: This snippet seems fair to me according this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qVUP/1/ :)

Comment: In fact your `retrievedScript` may contains errors so that would make the script crash.

Answer (score 0):

You say the entire thing is in a variable...I assume you mean as a string.  With a string representation of anything you can feasibly parse it for whatever you want.  The tricky part is doing it properly.  Take a look into RegEx (Regular Expressions) here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Here's a RegEx to find URL's:

```
^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
```

**Re: Comments**

You could concatenate all possible instances of said strings inside a BuildString() function and return a single string with the results, then regex the returned variable for your URLs.

IE:

```
function Concatenation() {
    var _strOutput = "<script>var x = 0; x += " + GetVariableIterator() + "; return x; </script>";
    return _strOutput;
}

function FinalResult() {
    var _strCombined = Concatenation();
    // Do Regex and work with URLs
}
```

Comment: Yes the script code to be parsed is in a string variable. I could use regex to catch the URLs that are defined simply as single strings, but that wouldn't catch URLs built from multiple variables or methods/functions like `replace()` etc.

Comment: Concatenating all the variables would catch more URLs, but still, there would be easy ways to get around this (for script authors trying to obfuscate URLs), eg. if the ajax `url:` line itself contained concatenated strings or functions without variables. I've added details to my original question explaining my goal if you're interested.