# Trying to get xhr response content in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from [bitclout](https://explorer.bitclout.com/?query-node=https:%2F%2Fapi.bitclout.com&block-height=0) using selenium. What I actually want to get is the response loaded against this url (https://api.bitclout.com/api/v1/block) in xhr tab. You'll get my point clearly by viewing below screenshot

[image]

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
>>> driver = Chrome()
>>> url = 'https://explorer.bitclout.com/?query-node=https:%2F%2Fapi.bitclout.com&block-height=0'
>>> driver.get(url)
```

I don't know what next to do to get that json response.

Comment: Not sure if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64523546/5223223) does the job.

Comment: Tested. In my case, `driver.requests[9].response.body` is the desired result.