# API request selenium Python

Tags: python, http, selenium-webdriver, networking

Maybe some can kindly help on the following issue.
I need to click on element and then to get the data which went to server and what is and endpoint in JSON format. The URL doesn't change only the API endpoint.

```
wait.until(EC.url_contains('/somedata/'))
    time.sleep(5)

    target_url = 'https://urlname'
    logs = driver.get_log("performance")
    for log in logs:
        message = log["message"]
        if "Network.responseReceived" in message:
            params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
            if params:
                response = params.get("response")
                if response:
                     if response and target_url in response["url"]:
                        body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': params["requestId"]})
                        logger.info(f'{body}')
                        print(f'{body}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not a tool to test internal websites API.

However, there is a python module called [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) that can help you listen the network traffic between the front-end (browser) and the back-end (web server).

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481212/capture-ajax-response-with-selenium-and-python).