# Login and logout in Node.js using authentication token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authentication

I'm working in Node.js Application. it requires login, logout ,and sign up functionalities I was thinking in creating the authentication using [token based](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543)   instead of cookies. and this will be the workflow

1. Send `POST /login` to the server to check if the user exist or not
2. if user exist I will send the token in JSON object and store it in the browser local storage
3. Now I want to redirect to home page after storing the token using `window.location = "/"`but **I need to insert the token in the header and this my problem** I found that's possible in angular using `$httpProvider.interceptors` that will intercept every  request and set its header.

Is there any way that I can do that without angular?

Comment: Intercept the requests with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796951/1387519) and add your header in there.

Comment: You can save the user in the session and then to create a middleware to verify if user has logged in (in each request).

Answer (score 0):

This is normally good concept when using an API and then a web app in front of it.

Basically you have to save your token and send it with every request, if you have it.

What I normally do is when I do the `/login` I store the token in the localStorage of the browser, you can use this library to use it https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API

Once you have the token in your localStorage, when you do a call to the API you check if there's the token in the localStorage, if there's add a header.

Here's an example using jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/data',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + localStorage.get('token')
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: that's not an answer . my question was I want to redirect to the home page after I get the token .. this will not happen using Ajax request

Comment: You have to save the token, and then use it for the next calls, if you don't have a JSAPP, you need a session to the server (with a cookie) because cookies are always sent to the server. While if you have a JSAPP in front, I guess, the client will make all the requests, so you can inject the token like I showed you.