# How to track http requests/responses using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to tack all the HTTP request and response made by webpage along with the response and request header. We  can use the chrome developer tool, firebug, charles, etc. **But i wanted to do the same using javaScript code**

Comment: Does that javascript have to live on the page? or can it be a browser plugin?  because there isn't a way to get "all" requests from js on the page.

Comment: No javascript wont be on page...

Comment: "A slightly more generic option that will intercept XHR calls from all frameworks" —http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796951/511795

Comment: If the javascript is not on the page it's more about the framework's APIs then the fact it's written in javascript.  As Shanimal points out you can intercept XHR, but that won't capture iframe, img, script, style sources in addition to a few other calls.

Comment: Can i track the request and response header of the of my ads code implemented on my webpage.