# Prevent intercepting XHR requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xss

Is there a way to prevent the intercepting of XHR requests from the global scope (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884616/intercept-all-ajax-calls))?

First, that comes to mind, pass XMLHttpRequest as a parameter to the application entry function (or IIFE) and make requests based on that copy (e.g. JQuery has an option for a custom XHR object). Is it reliable? Or there are other ways to intercept requests without altering XMLHttpRequest?

The concern is to handle a case when after a successful XSS attack, an attacker can intercept requests and steal the JWT from a header.

Comment: "[...] after a successful XSS attack" you have bigger problems than whatever you're trying to solve here. It's like... "they might nuke us, so how do we handle the foot soldiers?"

Comment: You are right, but sometimes you don't have control over everything.

Answer (score 1):

make it immutable:

```
const send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
delete XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'send', {value: send});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's looking promising. As an extra step, the XMLHttpRequest itself could be done as read-only.

Comment: what if someone managed to mutate it in the runtime prior to execution of this code?