# All AJAX request complete?

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous

I am working on a web site, and at some point in my code, I make some AJAX call:

`PART(I)`

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var id = arr[i].id;
        makeXHRRequest(id);
  }
```

and the `makeXHRRequest()`function is something like this:


`PART(II)`

```
function makeXHRRequest(id){
var jsonArg = ["id", id];
var jsonString = JsonBuilder(jsonArg);
var requestUrl = getUrl();

$.ajax({
      url: requestUrl,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: jsonString,
      datatype: "json",
      processdata: false,
      success: function (result, status) {
        console.log(result);
        // TODO check if result is valid
        if(result == null || result == ""){
         //...
        }else{
            for(var i = 0; i < parent.arr.length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < count; j++){
                   // !!!!! make another ajax call !!!!!!!!
                    makeAnotherXHRRequest(id);
                }
                }
            }
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          console.log("in get groupUsers fail");
      }
});
```

}

Note these are nested AJAX calls -> each ajax call made in `part(I)` above issues a bunch of sub-ajax calls in `part(II)`. So my question is, if the program want to do some task after all data is ready, how could the program knows when all requests made in `part(I)` and all request made in `part(II)` finished?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755186/tracking-with-java-script-if-ajax-request-is-going-on-in-a-webpage-or-intercept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in jQuery return [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), aka *promises*, which you can *listen* to if they are done or not. In your case, we can collect them into an array. Then we use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to listen to the promises if they are *all* resolved.

```
var promises = [];

function makeXHRRequest(id){
  ...
  //we return the ajax promise
  return $.ajax(..
  ...
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  ...
  //we store the promise
  promises.push(makeXHRRequest(id));
}


$.when
 .apply(null,promises) //listen to all the promises
 .done(function(){

   /*code here executes when all ajax promises resolves*/

 });
```