# Overriding XMLHttpRequest on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, browser, xmlhttprequest

I have to detect all ajax requests that are made in a specific web page (long story). The idea that I came with is overriding `XMLHttpRequest`.

I developed a simple script that does what I need. It works flawlessly on Firefox, Chrome, and Opera, but not on Internet Explorer. IE simply ignores the behavior I override.

**How can I override XMLHttpRequest on Internet Explorer**?

On Chrome (works):

[image]

On IE (doesn't work):

[image]

Comment: You need to isolate your test.

Comment: What do you mean by "isolate"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to detect it, you can override the open method.

```
(function(){
  var oOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    console.log("here");
    oOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}());
```

Comment: It also doesn't work on IE... I'm overriding the `send` method by the way, the ctor overriding is just an easy to reproduce example.

Comment: You might need to do it this way also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797960/extending-an-activexobject-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IE9. Switch to IE11 and it will work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to support older IE versions.